# ToolTip won't disappear after "x" seconds

Tags: vb.net, tooltip

I show a ToolTip like this:

```
Sub Form1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
  If e.KeyChar = ChrW(3) Then
    Clipboard.SetDataObject("X:" & MousePosition.X & "  " & "Y:" & MousePosition.Y)
    Me.ToolTip1.Show("Copied into the clipboard", Me.Label8)
  End If
End Sub
```

But the ToolTip doesn't disappear...

I have the correct values for "AutoPopDelay" (5000) and the other properties for my "ToolTip1", but if I call the ToolTip like the way that I've explained then I can do nothing to auto-close it after "X" seconds...

I've tried the "**thread.sleep**" method to wait "x" seconds after the ToolTip is launched to close it, but this method stops the process of my main form so I need a better way to do it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I repro.  ToolTip is a very quirky component.  You can whack it into shape somewhat by explicitly specifying the duration:

```
 Me.ToolTip1.Show("Copied into the clipboard", Label1, 1500)
```

Which will make it disappear as expected.  Still not quite right, clicking the tip to dismiss it temporarily deactivates the form.  Do favor another control for these kind of notifications, a StatusStrip.